# Need help on inserting a new row in main table from other table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a main table `table A` where the invoice number is unique and having a column like `item_bill_code, value, candidate_id`
another table `table B` I having column candidate id and `item_billcode, value`.
I am outing main table `table A`
I want all have to come to one table.

table A

```
invoic_no sno item_bill_code value   candidate_id
A0001     1   Stationary    100     E00100
A0001     2   other         200     E00100
A0002     1   Stationary    150     E00200
A0002     2   other         200     E00200
```

table b

```
candidate id   sno item_code value
E00100          1  leave     200
E00200          1  leave     250
```

combined value has to come

table A

```
invoic_no sno item_bill_code value   candidate_id
A0001     1   Stationary     100     E00100
A0001     2   other          200     E00100
A0001     3   Leave          200     E00100
A0002     1   Stationary     150     E00200
A0002     2   other          200     E00200
A0002     3   leave          250     E00200
```

I tried with union all but not able to do

```
declare @tablea as table 
(invoic_no varchar(100)
 ,sno int
 ,item_bill_code  varchar(100)
 ,value    numeric(15,3)
 ,candidate_id varchar(100))

 declare @tableb as table (
 candidate_id varchar(100)
  ,sno int
 ,item_bill_code  varchar(100)
 ,value    numeric(15,3)
 )

 insert into @tablea
 select 
'A0001',     1,   'Stationary',    100     ,'E00100'
union all
select
'A0001',     2,   'other',         200     ,'E00100'
union all
select
'A0002',     1,   'Stationary',    150     ,'E00200'
union all
select
'A0002',     2,   'other',         200     ,'E00200'

insert into @tableb
 select 
'E00100',     1,   'LEAVE',    100    
union all
select
'E00200',     1,   'LEAVE',         200     

select 

invoic_no 
 ,sno 
 ,item_bill_code  
 ,value   
 ,candidate_id 

from @tablea
union all

select null,max(sno),item_bill_code,value,candidate_id from @tableb
group by item_bill_code,value,candidate_id
```

I have tried like this but not able to get output

Comment: how can i understand that `sno` in `table B`

Comment: there is no sno in table  B  there will be always one "Leave" value in B table for that candidate, or else we can add sno in table B, but it will be always 1 for that candidate

Comment: What have you tried already? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @Sanguinary, the sql section of stackoverflow seems to be an exception ;)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Insert into ... SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO tableA (invoic_no,sno,item_bill_code,value,candidate_id)
SELECT a.invoic_no,
       MAX(a.sno) + 1,
       b.item_code,
       b.value,
       b.candidate_id
FROM tableA a JOIN tableb b ON a.candidate_id = b.candidate_id
GROUP BY 
       a.invoic_no,
       b.item_code,
       b.value,
       b.candidate_id
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from tableA
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a86e6/1/0)**:

```
| invoic_no | sno | item_bill_code | value | candidate_id |
|-----------|-----|----------------|-------|--------------|
|     A0001 |   1 |     Stationary |   100 |       E00100 |
|     A0001 |   2 |          other |   200 |       E00100 |
|     A0002 |   1 |     Stationary |   150 |       E00200 |
|     A0002 |   2 |          other |   200 |       E00200 |
|     A0001 |   3 |          leave |   200 |       E00100 |
|     A0002 |   3 |          leave |   250 |       E00200 |
```

Comment: what if B table having more item_bill_code for the same employee. does it will inser into A table as separate sno

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

Your Output desired like this.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT B.invoic_no,(Select MAX(sno) + 1 FROM tableA Where invoic_no = B.invoic_no) As srno,A.item_code,A.value,A.candidate_id
FROM 
    tableB A
    INNER JOIN 
    tableA B
    ON A.candidate_id = B.candidate_id
```

And insert into table A query below this.

```
INSERT INTO tableA
(
    invoic_no,  
    sno ,
    item_bill_code,  
    value   ,
    candidate_id
)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT B.invoic_no,(Select MAX(sno) + 1 FROM tableA Where invoic_no = B.invoic_no) As srno,A.item_code,A.value,A.candidate_id
FROM 
    tableB A
    INNER JOIN 
    tableA B
    ON A.candidate_id = B.candidate_id
```

Comment: B table not having an invoice number in the column

Comment: I know but I have set alias. tablea set alias B, and tableB alias set A.

Answer (score 0):

Left join helps. Note the order of tables. Try

```
declare @tablea as table (
  invoic_no varchar(100)
 ,sno int
 ,item_bill_code  varchar(100)
 ,value    numeric(15,3)
 ,candidate_id varchar(100));

 declare @tableb as table (
   candidate_id varchar(100)
  ,sno int
  ,item_bill_code  varchar(100)
  ,value    numeric(15,3));

 insert into @tablea
values('A0001',     1,   'Stationary',    100     ,'E00100')
,('A0001',     2,   'other',         200     ,'E00100')
,('A0001',     2,   'LEAVE',         200     ,'E00100')
,('A0002',     1,   'Stationary',    150     ,'E00200')
,('A0002',     2,   'other',         200     ,'E00200');

insert into @tableb
values('E00100',     1,   'LEAVE',    200)    
,('E00200',     1,   'LEAVE',         250)   
,('E00200',     2,   'LEAVE2',        270) ; 

-- what to insert
select invoic_no, max(sno)+ row_number() over( partition by invoic_no order by bi) sno, bi,bv, candidate_id
from (
    select invoic_no 
     ,a.sno 
     ,a.item_bill_code  
     ,a.value   
     ,a.candidate_id 
     ,b.item_bill_code bi
     ,b.value bv
    from @tableb b
    left join @tablea a
    on a.candidate_id = b.candidate_id
    where a.item_bill_code <> b.item_bill_code) t
group by invoic_no,bi,bv,candidate_id
```

I added more options in @tableb just for demo.
Returns

```
invoic_no   sno bi  bv  candidate_id
A0001   3   LEAVE   200.000 E00100
A0002   3   LEAVE   250.000 E00200
A0002   4   LEAVE2  270.000 E00200
```

Comment: it was very helpful...some suggestion was sno+1 but your answer has covered more problems..thanks once again